# How to filter unwanted values in arrays for plotting? ValueError in matplotlib using numpy arrays

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray, valueerror

I am working on a new routine inside some codes based on OOP, and encountered a problem while modifying the array of the data (short example of the code is below).

Basically, this routine is about taking the array **R**, transposing it and then sorting it, and then filter out the data below the pre-determined value of **thres**. Then, I re-transpose back this array into its original dimension, and then plot each of its rows with the first element of **T**.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R = np.random.rand(3,8)
R = R.transpose() # transpose the random matrix
R = R[R[:,0].argsort()] # sort this matrix
print(R)

T = ([i for i in np.arange(1,9,1.0)],"temps (min)")

thres = float(input("Define the threshold of coherence: "))

if thres >= 0.0 and thres <= 1.0 :
        R = R[R[:, 0] >= thres] # how to filter unwanted values? changing to NaN / zeros ?
else :
        print("The coherence value is absurd or you're not giving a number!")

print("The final results are ")
print(R)
print(R.transpose())
R.transpose() # re-transpose this matrix

ax = plt.subplot2grid( (4,1),(0,0) )
ax.plot(T[0],R[0])
ax.set_ylabel('Coherence')

ax = plt.subplot2grid( (4,1),(1,0) )
ax.plot(T[0],R[1],'.')
ax.set_ylabel('Back-azimuth')

ax = plt.subplot2grid( (4,1),(2,0) )
ax.plot(T[0],R[2],'.')
ax.set_ylabel('Velocity\nkm/s')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (min)')
```

However, I encounter an error

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (8,) and (3,)
```

I comment the part of where I think the problem might reside (*how to filter unwanted values?*), but then the question remains.

How can I plot this two arrays (**R** and **T**) while still being able to filter out unwanted values below **thres**? Can I transform these unwanted values to zero or NaN and then successfully plot them? If yes, how can I do that?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try changing your `T...` to `T=([i for i in np.linspace(1,9, R.shape[1] )],"temps (min)")`, and move it down below `if ... else` block. It will solve the mismatch dimension error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got some ideas from a friend and it worked as I want.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a techie friend, the problem is simply resolved by keeping this part

```
R = R[R[:, 0] >= thres]
```

because removing unwanted elements is more preferable than changing them to NaN or zero. And then the problem with plotting is fixed by adding a slight modification in this part

```
ax.plot(T[0][:len(R[0])],R[0])
```

and also for the subsequent plotting part. This slices **T** into the same dimension as **R**.